# memcached key of keys

Tags: php, memcached

Is it possible?

```
$mc = new Memcached();
$mc->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);
$data = array(

         'key_one' => array('something' => '0',
                          'something_else1' => 1,
                          'something_else2' => 2,
                          'something_else3' => 3,
                         ),

          'key_two' =>   array('something' => '0',
                         'something_else1' => 1,
                         'something_else2' => 2,
                         'something_else3' => 3,
                         )
         );
$result = $mc->get("data['key_one']['something_else2']");
if($result) {
  echo $result;
} else {
  echo "No data on Cache. Please refresh page pressing F5";
  $mc->set("data", $data,15) or die ("Failed to save data at Memcached server");
}
```

Comment: Step 1. Run your code. Step 2. Answer found.

Comment: The question should be "this does not work, how to make it work?"

Comment: yeap sorry this does not work how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `set()` should work:

```
$mc->set('data', $data, 15);
```

And to `get()`:

```
$result = $mc->get('data');
$something = $result['key_one']['something_else2'];
//or PHP >= 5.4.0
$result = $mc->get('data')['key_one']['something_else2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

No, will not work.
Memcached is a Key-Value store. So you can retrieve the data stored by a unique key.
What will work is:

```php
$_temp_result = $mc->get('key_one');
$result = $_temp_result['something_else2']
```

Assuming the data is stored in Memcached as shown in `$data`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm okey but how about set multi, wich could be correct?

```
$mc->set('data')['key_deeper_1'],$value, $expired_time);

or

$data = array('key_1' => array(
                                  'key_deeper_1' => 'value',
                                  'key_deeper_2' => 'value',

                              )
             );

$mc->set('data',$value, $expired_time);
$mc-> get('data')['key_deeper_1'];
```